# Disabled all other inputfields when 1 inputfield is filled in doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, readonly, input-field

I have 3 input textfields, but whenever the first one is filled in, the other 2 inputfields should be disabled. I'm trying to do this as shown below and disabling the 2 input fields is working fine, but when I delete my input they stay disabled and they don't get their readonly= false. Any ideas for a solution? Working with Jquery in ASP.net!

FRONTEND:

```
<p><asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" CssClass="texter" placeholder="<%$ Resources:GlobalResource, title%>"  ></asp:TextBox></p>
<p><asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server" CssClass="texter" placeholder="<%$ Resources:GlobalResource, status%>"  ></asp:TextBox></p>
<p><asp:TextBox ID="txtMessageId" runat="server" CssClass="texter" placeholder="<%$ Resources:GlobalResource, messageid%>" ></asp:TextBox></p>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTitle").change(function () {
        if (!$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTitle").value != ''){
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtStatus").prop("readonly", true);
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMessageId").prop("readonly", true);
        }
        else {
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtStatus").prop("readonly", false);
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMessageId").prop("readonly", false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: is `$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTitle")` selecting anything? is that the rendered html?

Comment: Yes it is, because. Setting them readonly = true works fine. But if I delete my input then the others are still disabled and they should be editable again but that somehow goes wrong. (should've put that in the info as well, will do in a minute)

Comment: my question was because I don't c anything with `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTitle` as id in your html, I have not worked with asp.net but still it's really odd

Comment: With asp.net if you have to get something server-side (like with jquery/javascript) then it adds 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_' to your id. So that's definitely not wrong. I guess the IF- line should be changed but.

Comment: there, that's exactly why I asked you if that was the RENDERED html, not the html in your file where you r coding, but the one you could, for instance, copy from the browser source code AFTER it has been rendered, that's the one that could be useful here, when `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTitle` already actually exists in the dom

Comment: It actually is the ID that is rendered, this is the ID I found when doing 'inspecting elements' in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

I worked with *keyup* instead of *onchange* AND *length > 0* instead of *!= ''*

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTitle").keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0 ) {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtStatus").prop("readonly", true);
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMessageId").prop("readonly", true);
    }
    else {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtStatus").prop("readonly", false);
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMessageId").prop("readonly", false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will work if you use keyup event instead of change event. Change I would use on dropdowns for example.

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTitle").keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).value != ''){
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtStatus").prop("readonly", true);
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMessageId").prop("readonly", true);
    }
    else {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtStatus").prop("readonly", false);
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMessageId").prop("readonly", false);
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: Nope, readonly still doesn't convert back to false when the input field is empty again.

Comment: okay, your answer is almost the same as my code apart from the `length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

1. Maybe you should use `'input'` so changes take effect immediately instead of after the current text box loses focus, or maybe that is your goal.
2. With jQuery, use `.val()` instead of `.value`
3. `!` dunno what for.
4. Just for performance, use `$(this)` instead of re-querying with `$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTitle")`

as you can see, I included three generic `input`s to work with in the snippet, I hope the gist is there

let me know

```js
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTitle").on('input', function () {
        if ($(this).val() != ''){
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtStatus").prop("readonly", true);
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMessageId").prop("readonly", true);
        }
        else {
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtStatus").prop("readonly", false);
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMessageId").prop("readonly", false);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTitle"/>
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtStatus"/>
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMessageId"/>
```

Comment: Still the same problem as before. They do get their 'readonly = true' but when you delete everything in the input box the other inputs are still readonly while they should be editable again. (on the other hand, I do use this but when something doesnt work (like this time) I always break down to the essence of everuthing to see where my problem might be).

Comment: @ManuelvandenNotelaer, hi I just saw your comment. *"but when you delete everything in the input box the other inputs are still readonly"* not true, at least not in the snippet I included. unless I'm misunderstanding your goal which is: **make** `txtStatus` **and** `txtMessageId` **readonly if** `txtTitle` **is non-empty and make them editable otherwise**. please do tell me where I got it wrong